# AJAX status 12030

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-status-codes

I am sending an ajax XMLHttpRequest using the POST method. When the request is sent, I am getting a readyState of 4 with a status of 12030. I know 12030 is a Microsoft specific state code that indicate the connection was not sustained. However, I can't seem to find where my code would be causing this error. If I navigate to the page without using the ajax request, it loads fine. Below is the javascript method and the call line.

AJAX Method

```
/*Sends ajax request with post data that updates the content view via ajax on completion
* @param message : message after completion of ajax request
* @param url : url to request
* @param params : post parameters as string
*/
function changeAjaxPost(message, url, params) {
    var ajx;
    if (window.HXMLHttpRequest) {
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE, "Using XMLHttpRequest");
        ajx = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE, "Using ActiveXObject");
        ajx = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    ajx.open("POST", url, true);
    ajx.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    ajx.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    ajx.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    ajx.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    ajx.send(params);
    ajx.onreadystatechange = function () {
        document.write(ajx.readyState + ":" + ajx.status);
        if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 200) {
            alert(message);
            updateContent();
        }
        else if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 400) {
            alert("Page Error. Please refresh and try again.");
        }
        else if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 500) {
            alert("Server Error. Please refresh and try again.");
        }
    }

}
```

Call Line

```
changeAjaxPost("Excerpt Saved", "./AJAX/myadditions_content.aspx", params);
```

Comment: I don't understand why people are still using plain JS to do ajax. jQuery will simplify your life! http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: are you getting this ajax error constantly or just randomly? how long does the ajax call take?

Comment: @Dutchie432 It's not always a choice. Companies can mandate it (discovercard.com was like that for a long time), or you could be developing a framework agnostic library.

Comment: Fair enough - but can we agree, that aside from that, there's virtually no good reason?

Comment: Agreed. Also, @steventnorris, you should know that setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); can cause problems with newer browsers.

Comment: @TobiasKrogh It's consistent. Every request returns the same status code. It's fairly instantaneous.

Comment: @mikerobinson I'm developing for IE7. I'm not as familiar with HTTPRequest headers as I'd like to be. I found the headers portion from another coders suggestion for POST ajax. What exactly does connection:close do?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Removing that request header worked perfectly. If you will post as an answer and give a little explanation on what connection:close means, I'll be more than glad to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, using

```
setRequestHeader("Connection","close");
```

can cause problems in some browsers.

Removing this solves the problem.

Credit goes to @MikeRobinson

Answer (score 1):

http://danweber.blogspot.com/2007/04/ie6-and-error-code-12030.html

IE6 and error code 12030
If you are running Internet Explorer 6 and using Ajax, you may get some XMLHttpRequests terminated with code 12030.
Microsoft's knowledge base at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193625 shows that this code is

12030       ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_ABORTED
              The connection with the server has been terminated.
Googling turned up no help; the people encountering this don't seem to be aware of how network sockets work, so I had to actually figure it out on my own.

This happens when the client thinks a connection has been kept open, and the server thniks it is closed. The server has sent a FIN, and the client has responded to that with an ACK. Running "netstat" on the Windows client shows that the connection is in the CLOSE_WAIT state, so IE6 really *ought* to have realized this before trying. This is entirely the client's fault. If you wait about 60 seconds, the Windows OS stack will retire the connection.

If you need to support IE6, you have some solutions, in various degrees of ugly:

retry the ajax request in case of error code 12030
if the browser is ie, send an empty request to the server ahead of each ajax request
bundle up your ajax requests such that the time between them is ( (greater than server_timeout) AND (less than server_timeout + one minute)
IE7, fwiw, will issue a RST over the CLOSE_WAIT socket as soon as it realizes it has an outgoing connection to make. That, and the socket will only stay in that CLOSE_WAIT state for about 5 seconds anyway.